# Match right to left not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

So what's happening. I  have a planned lot number and production lot number

In K5 I have the planned lot number as F31807010902

The production lot number FRD 03201807010902 is on another sheet with all the production lot numbers called Prod Time.

What I am to trying to do a wildcard search so that F31807010902 turns into *1807010902 and search for that in the 'Prod Time Sheet' so I can pull the corresponding date.
The 'Prod Time' sheet is layed out as

Prod Date-----Run Time-----Prod Lot#-----Qty

Solution 1 Tried

```
=INDEX('Prod Time'!A4:D4000,MATCH("*"&MID(K5,3,10),'Prod Time'!A4:D4000&"",0))
```

Solution 2 Tried

```
=VLOOKUP("*"&MID(K5,3,10),CHOOSE({1,2},'Prod Time'!A4:4000,'Prod Time'!A4:D4000),1,0)
```

Is there something wrong with my arguments or do I have to take a completely different approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Match only wants a single column or a single row, not a two dimensional range. Use the range in which you want to search the value.

```
=INDEX('Prod Time'!A4:A4000,MATCH("*"&MID(K5,3,10),'Prod Time'!C4:C4000&"",0))
```

And this is an array formula meaning it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting Edit mode

Comment: That got me exactly what I needed. Thank you so much!